# Why this code capturing self inside this block compile in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, self, lazy-initialization

I work in a project were I came across multiples cases like this,

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   private let clearCacheButton: UIButton = {
       let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
       button.setTitle(AppMessages.General.Action.clearCache.description, for: .normal)
       button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clearCache), for: .touchUpInside)
       return button
   }()
}
```

self is being captured to add target for button, yet compiler does not complain about capturing self before initialisation, it works even without `lazy var` modifier...

Why is that?
Is this just a little convenience added by Apple at some point?

If I remember well it was not possible in the past

Thank you for the replies

Comment: That is because you're actually executing a function that assigns the value. Non-static Functions have access to `self` I do this all the time.

Comment: If you remove the `()` and the `=` the compiler will freak.

Comment: I have never actually researched this, so take my understanding with a grain of salt. But I have been under the impression that the compiler just looks at it like a function. It executes on initialization. Self is available before the execution actually occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler has never complained about this. But it should (and I have filed a bug on this point), because the code you've written won't work: the button will not actually do anything when tapped. (The app might even crash, but then again it might not.)

The reason (for both phenomena) is that the compiler *misinterprets* the term `self` here to mean the *class* — which does exist before initialization of the instance.

The solution is to replace `let` by `lazy var`. That does work, because now the code will not actually be called until some later, when the instance *does* exist.

Comment: Interesting. I did not know about this bug. Thanks for the explanation. (Voted.)

Comment: If the compiler interprets `self` to mean the class rather than an instance of the class, shouldn't it the complain that the selector doesn't exist for that target? (unless the **class** also happens to have a method with the same signature) I guess saying "why isn't the bug implemented properly" is a little silly, but I'm still curious what's going on under the covers.

Comment: compiler misinterprets the term self here to mean the class - why?

Comment: " the compiler misinterprets the term self here to mean the class". That is not correct. And it is not a bug that this code compiles. Target/Action – in the underlying Objective-C Runtime – is a runtime-based messaging system. At compile time there is no check if _self_ is assigned or not, this will only happen at runtime.

Comment: The crazy part is that this code actually works! there's no error when running the app, no crashes or even warnings when tapping the button everything works as expected,

and I could not find anything on google explaining why this works

Comment: @Lucas: you could google for Objective-C responder chain. And if you're really interested in that stuff, you could check out https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/objective-c_runtime.

Comment: @lukas.j what the responder chain has to do with the discussed question?

Comment: See my bug report and the comments thereon: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4865 It talks about the responder chain too. You can wind up with a nil-targeted action and so nothing happens.

Comment: And see, always see, my famous rant: https://www.biteinteractive.com/rant-swift-cocoa-target-action/